# Modify format section headers on Mobile.css Mediawiki

Tags: html, css, mobile, mediawiki

I'm using Mediawiki and I would like to change the format (size, bold, italic) of the section headers for the mobile version of the site. I tried to add in the Mediawiki:Mobile.css as in the Mediawiki:Commons.css :

```
#bodyContent h1, firstHeading { font-size: 24px; }
#bodyContent h2 { font-size: 170% !important; font-style:bold !important; }
#bodyContent h3 { font-size: 150% !important; font-style:bold !important; }
#bodyContent h4 { font-size: 140% !important; font-style:bold !important; }
#bodyContent h5 { font-size: 130% !important; font-style:bold !important; }
#bodyContent h6 { font-size: 120% !important; font-style:italic; }
```

But it doesn't change anything. Does anyone know how to do?

Thanks by advance.

Comment: Are you using the MobileFrontend extension? Have you enabled [$wgUseSiteCss](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgUseSiteCss)?

Comment: I didn't enable it, but it seems it was by default. I've tried to add $wgUseSiteCss = true; but the display is still the same. Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Try to right-click the headers and click "inspect", check which styles are applied.

Comment: I can't find where we see which styles are applied. Could you help me?